# Does the LCG fail the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test as badly as my code suggests?

Tags: python, random, statistics, distribution

I use the following `Python` code to illustrate the generation of random variables to students:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def lcg(n, x0, M=2**32, a=1103515245, c=12345):
    result = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        result[i] = (a*x0 + c) % M
        x0 = result[i]

    return np.array([x/M for x in result])

x = lcg(10**6, 3)
print(stats.kstest(x, 'uniform'))
```

The default parameters are the ones used by glibc, according to Wikipedia. The last line of the code prints

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.043427751892089805, pvalue=0.0)
```

The pvalue of 0.0 indicates that the observation would basically never occur if the elements of `x` were truly distributed according to a uniform distribution.
My question is: is there a bug in my code, or does the LCG with the parameters given not pass the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with `10**6` replicas?

Comment: What version of  Python do you use? Division is different in Python 2 vs Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem with your code, it makes uniform distribution like

[image]

I've changed your LCG implementation a bit, and all is good now (Python 3.7, Anaconda, Win10 x64)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lcg(n, x0, M=2**32, a=1103515245, c=12345):
    result = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        x0 = (a*x0 + c) % M
        result[i] = x0

    return np.array([x/float(M) for x in result])

#x = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 1000000)
x = lcg(1000000, 3)
print(stats.kstest(x, 'uniform'))

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(x, 15, density=True)
plt.plot(bins, np.ones_like(bins), linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

which prints

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.0007238884545415214, pvalue=0.6711878724246786)
```

and plots

[image]

UPDATE

as @pjs pointed out, you'd better divide by float(M) right in the loop, no need for
second pass over whole array

```
def lcg(n, x0, M=2**32, a=1103515245, c=12345):
    result = np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        x0 = (a*x0 + c) % M
        result[i] = x0 / float(M)

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement Severin's answer, the reason my code was not working properly is that `result` was an array of floating point numbers.
We can see the difference between the two implementations already at the second iteration.
After the first iteration, `x0 = 3310558080`.

```
In [9]: x0 = 3310558080

In [10]: float_x0 = float(x0)

In [11]: (a*x0 + c) % M
Out[11]: 465823161

In [12]: (a*float_x0 + c) % M
Out[12]: 465823232.0

In [13]: a*x0
Out[13]: 3653251310737929600

In [14]: a*float_x0
Out[14]: 3.6532513107379297e+18
```

So the problem had to do with the use of floating point numbers.

Comment: The reason your code didn't work is because you used `x0 = result[i]` rather than `result[i] = x0` and neglected to divide by `float(M)`.

Comment: @pjs he divided by float(M) but at the very end, very inefficient

Comment: updated my answer with a bit more efficient implementation

Comment: Dividing by `float(M)` or `M` does not matter, from my experiments.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos True in python 3, not true in python 2.  You didn't specify which you're using when Severin asked, and `float(M)` works in both cases.

Comment: @pjs Thanks, TIL :) I agree with you.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos when I asked I thought problem is related to division by M and you're using Python 2. Then I found out it is float-to-int conversion, but just in case left float(M) in the code.